# Reading a determined size of a string from end of file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I appended a string to a file by `fs.appendFileSync()` and then I want to get it from that file. I try to use `fs.readSync` . But it returns `Error: Unknown encoding: 6` . How can I get the appended string from a file in Node.js? I know the size of string.
My code for appending:

```
fs.appendFileSync('A.dmg','behdad');
```

and for reading the appended string:

```
var fd = fs.openSync('A.dmg','w+');
var buffer = '';
var res = fs.readSync(fd,buffer,0,6,fs.statSync('A.dmg').size);
console.log(buffer);
console.log(res);
```

Edited:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fd = fs.openSync('A.dmg','r+');
var size = fs.statSync('A.dmg').size;
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(size);
var res = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, size, 0);
console.log(buffer.toString());
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand the difference between `r+` and `w+` modes:

> `r+`: Open a text file for update (that is, for both reading and
>   writing).
>   `w+`: Open a text file for update (reading and writing),
>   first truncating the file to zero length if it exists or creating the
>   file if it does not exist.

Since you want to open the file for reading and maybe updating it later, you should open the file in `r+` mode.

Second, the last argument passed to `fs.readSync()` in your code doesn't make sense to me. The last argument is the `position`.  If you really want to read the 6 characters, then why specify the position of the file pointer to 6? You want to read the file from the start, right?

Now, coming back to the main point: The second argument passed to `readSync()` in your code is of datatype: `String`, which is immutable. So, now the call to `fs.readSync()` falls back to the old syntax...

> `fs.readSync(fd, length, position, encoding)`: Synchronous version of `fs.read`. Returns an array `[data, bytesRead]`.

...and it thinks that 6 is the encoding which you wish to specify, which is clearly not the case.

Hence, if you are using a new version of node, your code should be something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFileSync('A.dmg','behdad');
var fd = fs.openSync('A.dmg','r+');
var size = fs.statSync('A.dmg').size;
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(size);
var res = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, size, 0);
console.log(buffer.toString());
console.log(res);
```

If you are using an old version of node:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFileSync('A.dmg','behdad');
var fd = fs.openSync('A.dmg','r+');
var size = fs.statSync('A.dmg').size;
var res = fs.readSync(fd, size, 0, 'utf8');
console.log(res);
```

Read the discussion at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2820

Comment: It returns an empty string and `0` in second line. I want to read just appended text, I am using this way to assign a unique text to my file and later read that unique text to identify the file. Thank you for information.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Did you change the mode to 'r+' ?

Comment: Yes , but it returns empty string.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Is A.dmg empty? :)

Comment: I really get confused! `A.dmg` is dmg of Keybase application which I am testing on. But now when I test it and ran it with another file, it works!

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Use `fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, x, size - x);` where x is the number of bytes you want to read from the end of file

Comment: Thank you. I am developing Swift and Javascript together at same time, because of it I really get confused that I didn't check the `A.dmg` file size.